# How to add Struts 2 business service

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, struts2

Today I sat for practical test for a job. In that paper they were ask to create small web application for submit some data to DB and separate layers (MVC) correctly.

So I used Struts 2, Spring, and Hibernate integration for that application.

Also I used BO and DAO classes.

Test is like this, Students are inquire about subjects. One student can inquire many subjects,
they should submit name email and subject and message.

So, I have done data submit part correctly. But as last question they ask to validate email address that same email address cannot use more than 3 time for a day. As a hint they give use Business service.

I'm not able to do that and I want to know how that can be done?

Comment: Did you say them that you not able to do so?

Comment: I'm not able to done only validation part.

Comment: Did you use Struts2 validation framework?

Comment: Nope. I used only basic things.
Action class and BO and DAO.
That app same as this example. 
http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-spring-hibernate-integration-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they given you a service you should use it instead of DAO. The validation is easy by extending `ActionSupport` and overriding a `validate()` method. This validation type is called *programmatic*, because you are not defining rules for the validators but continue to validate manually by checking the action state and other conditions and add errors via `ActionSupport::addActionError()` or `ActionSupport::addFieldError()` methods that has a default implementation. For example

```
public void validate() {
  if (sameEmailAddressCannotUseMoreThan3TimeForADay(emailAddress))
   addActionError("same email address cannot use more than 3 time for a day");
}
```

It could be adjusted with `ActionSupport::getText()` and `MessageFormat::format()` to represent a message as error.

The `defaultStack` includes `validation` interceptor, so use the default and don't forget to configure `INPUT` result. When errors are collected from the validation the `INPUT` result returns and action is not executing. The errors are displayed in the JSP via `<s:actionerror/>` or `<s:fielderror/>`.

**References:**

- [WebWork Validation](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/01/19/webwork-validation.html)
- [Struts 2 ActionError & ActionMessage Example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-actionerror-actionmessage-example/)

Comment: Got it.
So I must define "sameEmailAddressCannotUseMoreThan3TimeForADay(emailAddress)" method in BO class. And check it with db right?

Comment: Yes, it's a validation logic. You can use a business services to implement it, so implementation might vary.